# PHP - IPP printer class not printing specific PDF file

Tags: php, file, pdf, printing

The IPP class is printing PDF properly, but it is not printing specific file of SWIFT which is in PDF. I tried all possible attribute in IPP class which had no result.

> The main purpose of running this application is to scan the SWIFT folder for PDF files, then print each file PDF in specific printer and move the file to backup folder.

```
require_once('php_classes/PrintIPP.php');

$clientPath = "../swiftapp/public/_assets/getfile/";
$pdffiles     = array();
$valid_files  = array('pdf');

$ipp = new PrintIPP();

if(is_dir($clientPath)){
    foreach(scandir($clientPath) as $file){

        $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if(in_array($ext, $valid_files)){

            array_push($pdffiles, $file);
            $filePath = $clientPath.$file;
        
            // IPP printer configuration
            $ipp->setHost('172.18.0.98');
            $ipp->setPort(631);
            $ipp->setPrinterURI('./printers/NPIAB29B2 (HP LaserJet M402dn)');
            
            // IPP file configuration
            $ipp->setDocumentName($file);
            $ipp->setMimeMediaType('application/pdf');
            $ipp->unsetFidelity();
            $ipp->setCharset('utf-8');
            
            // Set PDF data for print
            $ipp->setData($getInsideFile);
            
            // send file for print
            $getPrintObj = $ipp->printJob();

            if($getPrintObj == 'successfull-ok'){

                $destinationFilePath = '../swiftapp/public/_assets/copyfile/'.$file;

                if( rename($filePath, $destinationFilePath) ) {
                    echo "<p style='color:#fff; 68b631'>$file file has been moved.</p>";
                } else {
                    echo "<p style='color:#EB1000'>File can't be moved!</p>";
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

This link is one of the real PDF file which IPP cant print it [PDF file for print](http://alfaplusinc.com/azb/26438572_20201026065251.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first thing is that the file was allegedly created by Ghostscript 9.27 which I find alarming if this is the SWIFT banking network, as that version of Ghostscript has significant well-publicised security vulnerabilities.

That said, it looks to me like either the Producer field is incorrect or someone edited the file after it was created. Or, just possibly, the creator used a broken build of Ghostscript, which would raise the question of where they got it from.

In any event, the file is broken. Badly so. The end of the file has the startxref token, which should be an offset into the file where the xref token can be found given like this:

```
startxref
%ld
%%EOF
```

Obviously %ld looks remarkably like it's an argument to sprintf. In addition the xref table itself is invalid:

```
xref
0 %ld
0000000000 65535 f 
        %ld 00000 n 
        %ld 00000 n 
        %ld 00000 n 
        %ld 00000 n 
        %ld 00000 n 
        %ld 00000 n 
        %ld 00000 n 
        %ld 00000 n 
        %ld 00000 n 
        %ld 00000 n 
        %ld 00000 n 
        %ld 00000 n 
        %ld 00000 n 
        %ld 00000 n
```

I've never seen **any** version of Ghostscript which would produce a file broken in that way.

You could run the file back through Ghostscript to the pdfwrite device which will repair the file for you, producing a PDF file which you can then print, but I don't really recommend that as standard practice.

If you open the file in Acrobat and then close it, Acrobat will offer to 'save the changes' (a fairly good sign the file is damaged) and produce a fixed file for you.

Other than that, you need to go back to whoever is creating these files and tell them they are making garbage.

Comment: I follow all your instruction. and find that we files are damaged, according on what you said ( **If you open the file in Acrobat and then close it, Acrobat will offer to 'save the changes' (a fairly good sign the file is damaged) and produce a fixed file for you.** ).

Now, we can change anything from SWIFT side. we need to find a solution for this problem at our side. is there any possibility to shot damaged files to print?

Comment: I **really** think you should let whoever is producing these files know there is a problem, the file you supplied is really, really badly broken. I made two suggestions in my answer which would allow you to create a repaired version of the file; either open the file and save it from Acrobat, or use Ghostscript's pdfwrite device to produce a new PDF file from the old one, repairing it in the process. Be aware that if you start from a broken PDF file there is no guarantee that it will be possible to repair it or that the repaired file will be correct.